# AngularJS extend Controller within controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, extend

here's my issue: I want to run the code of controllerB into  controllerA. The issue is that while the variables are returned to the controllerA, the values from requests are never returned. Here's a plunker to show the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/GqC9BOKTi8HxQLf2a2yd?p=preview

```
var test = $scope.$new();
$controller('Ctrl1', {$scope : test});

//the first 2 lines are executed, but the 3d never returns a value
$scope.variable = test.variable;
$scope.varFromFunction = test.varFromFunction();
$scope.varFromRequest = test.varFromRequest;
```

The first 2 lines execute, but the 3d one never returns a value.

Comment: Use a service to communicate or share code between controllers like here maybe http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/xqdxg/. I'm not sure if $controller is meant to be used in apps, probably just for testing.

Comment: That is probably dangerous and misleading. In your plunker you have 2 instances of `Ctrl1`. If it is meant to share information between the 2 controllers then this won't work. For this scenario it's better to use a _service_.

Answer (score 0):

Since `varFromRequest` is located inside a $timeout method in the first controller with 500ms, it will execute 500s later meanwhile angular completes its linking phase.

Watching `varFromRequest` in the second controller is the easy solution

```
 test.$watch('varFromRequest', function(new_value, old){
  $scope.varFromRequest = test.varFromRequest;

})
```

Here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/TqSjeckrdqeKquEbCwFX

Answer (score 0):

The `varFromFunction` is undefined when the second controller tries to get a reference. The timeout sets this var after this request. If you delay the request for reference then you will get the appropriate value. This isn't the recommended way of working but it does answer your question why it hasn't been set yet.

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.variable = 'OH HAI';
    $scope.varFromFunction = function(){
      return "OH HAI FromFunction";
    }
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.varFromRequest = "time";
    },500);

}]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$controller', '$timeout', function($scope, $controller, $timeout) {
    var test = $scope.$new();
    $controller('Ctrl1', {$scope : test});

    $scope.variable = test.variable;
    $scope.varFromFunction = test.varFromFunction();
    $scope.varFromRequest = test.varFromRequest || 'unset';

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.varFromRequest = test.varFromRequest || 'still unset';
    },500);
}]);
```